# For $A \in \mathcal {E}$ exist disjoint intervals $I_1,...,I_n$ with $A =I_1 \cup ... \cup I_n$

Tags: measure-theory

$\mathcal {E}$ is the union of finite intervals in $\mathbb{R}^d$. For $A \in \mathcal {E}$ exist disjoint intervals $I_1,...,I_n$ with $A =I_1 \cup ... \cup I_n$.

How do I show this?

Comment: What do you mean by intervals in $\mathbb{R}^d$? Product of $d$ intervals of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No, I mean $d$ as dimension

Comment: Yeah but what is an interval then? How do you define order to define intervals?

Comment: @LucasGiraldiA.Coimbra I'd wager it's just a product of intervals of $\mathbb{R}$, as you said.

Answer (score 1):

Lemma: For any two finite intervals $I,J$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $I \setminus J$ is a finite disjoint union of finite intervals: $I \setminus J = \bigcup_{i=1}^{m} K_i$.  You can see this vividly in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by drawing some pictures. And the pictures will indicate how to prove it.

For the main result do an induction on $n$. The key step is $n=2$: Given $A = I_1 \cup I_2$, write $A$ as $A =  I_1 \cup (I_2 \setminus I_1)$, then by the lemma $A = I_1 \cup \bigcup_{i=1}^{m} K_i$ where $K_i$ are disjoint intervals. Each $K_i$ is also disjoint from $I_1$ because they are subsets of $I_2 \setminus I_1$.